# Access issue while creating zip in C#

Tags: c#

I was trying to create a zip file programmatically in C#.
Unfortunately the below line keeps throwing error for some unknown reason.

```
Package zip = ZipPackage.Open("E:\\Logs",System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
                                         System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

> Access to the path "E:\Logs" is denied.

I tried some diff piece of code, but I had the same issue

```
FileStream fs = File.Create("E:\\Logs");
```

Not sure what could be the reason. Appreciate if this could be resolved.

Comment: Is `e:\logs` a directory?

Comment: Try changing the character \ with \\.
Package zip = ZipPackage.Open("E:\\Logs",System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite);

Comment: The exception tells you what the problem is - your program can't access the path. Most likely the program doesn't have write permissions in the given folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must use \\ instead of \.

Second, Open method accept a file name. So you must use it like this:

```
Package zip = ZipPackage.Open("D:\\a.zip",System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

Comment: Your analysis was bang on.. Thanks Chen

Comment: Note that Logs could be a file name, a file doesn't have to have an extention.

Comment: Yes, you are right, RonanThibaudau. The "Access to the path "E:\Logs" is denied." exception occurred because D:\Logs is a folder name.

Answer (score 1):

It gives you the answer in the error, you don't have access to that area, you're trying to create a file in the root directory of your drive and you don't have the user rights to do that, it's the same if you don't do it programatically, if you try to create a file named logs at the root of C on any modern version of Windows you will get told you need to elevate to administrator access.